# Delete item from array and law of demeter combo issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, controller, law-of-demeter

I have my show action as below:

```
def show
  @car = Car.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @cars = @car.other_cars_in_showroom
end
```

My Car model with appropriate method is:

```
def other_cars_in_showroom
  cars = self.showroom.cars
  cars.delete(self)
  cars
end
```

My issue is, the above works and the page renders fine, however, after a page refresh I get:

> undefined method `cars' for nil:NilClass

The error is on the `self.showroom.cars` line. How can I resolve this? All I require is to retrieve a list of all other cars in the same showroom as `@car` but then to remove the currently display car from the list so as to reduce the duplication.

On my view I am taking `@cars` and rendering this view for each of them:

```
<div class="car__photo">
  <div class="car__photo-inner">
    <%= image_tag car.s3_photo(:thumb), class: 'styled-picture' %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="car__info">
  <h4 class="car__info__name"><%= car.name %></h4>
  <p class="car__info__park"><%= car.park_name %></p>
</div>

<%= link_to car.name + ' at ' + car.showroom_name, car_path(car), class: 'car__link' %>
```

My expected output is for @cars to be a list of all the cars in the same showroom as @car but without @car itself.

Comment: Can you please add input and the expected output. Please share your show view also.

Comment: I'm not sure what input you wish me to provide but I have rewritten my question as I rejigged a few things around to move more to my Car model and I still get similar errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `undefined method 'cars' for nil:NilClass` error because `cars.delete(self)` is actually deleting the current car from database.

```
def other_cars_in_showroom
  cars = self.showroom.cars
  cars.delete(self) ## Fires delete query for self(deletes current car)
  cars
end
```

Update the show action as below, to get all the other cars in the showroom of the selected car except the selected car:

```
def show
  @car = Car.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @cars = @car.other_cars_in_showroom
end
```

Update the `other_cars_in_showroom` as below:

```
def other_cars_in_showroom
  showroom.cars.where.not(id: self.id)
end
```

Comment: Why would the .delete remove that car from my database? Surely it will just delete it from the Collection Array of @cars?  That's what I intended anyway.  Also why remove the other_cars_in_showroom method? Surely it's best to have that logic in my model so I can use it elsewhere?

Comment: Try this on `rails console`. `c=Car.first` then `c.showroom.cars.delete(c)`. You will see delete qauery being fired.

Comment: If you wish to keep the logic in model you can easily convert and move the `@car.showroom.cars.where.not(id: @car.id)` part in some other method.

Comment: Ok, Will give that a go shortly. Thankyou!

Comment: I am eager to know whether my answer resolved your query or not? :)

Comment: My apologies, Only had a short amount of time to try it out in since I have been back at home. Yes, it worked perfectly!